# QuillJS / Parchment : Controlling Nesting Order?

Tags: quill

I'm using QuillJS and Parchment and loving it so far!

That said, I've encountered a minor annoyance that I'm hoping someone knows the answer to. (I've combed the documentation, issues, questions, and even poked at the source code - trying to do due diligence before asking here!)

Is there any way to implicitly or explicitly control the order in which formatting tags are applied?

---

For instance, suppose you go to the [QuillJS Playground](https://quilljs.com/playground/) and paste in the text:

```
A (bold (italic (underlined))) move!
```

And even go so far as to format it so it looks like this:

A **(bold *(italic _(pretend this is underlined)_)*)** move!

The markup will be something deliciously like this:

```
<p>A <strong>(bold <em>(italic <u>(underlined)</u>)</em>)</strong> move!</p>
```

A beautiful little nesting of tags. Note that the order in which you apply the formats doesn't matter - it will always produce the same markup.

---

If instead, you go to the [QuillJS Playground](https://quilljs.com/playground/) and paste in the text:

```
An (underlined (italic (bold))) move!
```

And format it so it looks like this:

An _pretend this is (underlined *(italic **(bold)**)*)all the way to here_ move!

The markup will be something hideously like this:

```
<p>An <u>(underlined </u>
<em><u>(italic </u></em>
<strong><em><u>(bold)</u></em></strong><em><u>)</u></em>
<u>)</u> move!</p>
```

It follows the same nesting order as the first example (`<u>` is always inside of `<em>` is always inside of `<strong>`) which is wonderful! It just so happens that the stacking order of our text happens to be forcing it to nest awkwardly.

---

The reason I ask is because I'm defining a custom inline blot `<figcaption>` and I'd much rather have my markup look like this:

```
<figcaption>A <strong>bold</strong> move!</figcaption>
```

instead of this:

```
<figcaption>A </figcaption>
<strong><figcaption>bold</figcaption></strong>
<figcaption> move!</figcaption>
```

---

Any ideas? Suggestions?

***Thank you for your time!***

Answer (score 4):

***Eureka!***

I did some further digging through the QuillJS source, and stumbled upon this guy:

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/blots/inline.js#L44

```
// Lower index means deeper in the DOM tree, since not found (-1) is for embeds
Inline.order = [
  'cursor', 'inline',   // Must be lower
  'code', 'underline', 'strike', 'italic', 'bold', 'script',
  'link'                // Must be higher
];
```

The nesting order of inline elements is controlled by that array. Given two formats (say, `'bold'` and `'underline'`), `'underline'` will always be nested inside of `'bold'` because it occurs first in `Inline.order`. Likewise, `'link'` will always surround `'bold'` because `'link'` occurs after bold in that order.

To solve my problem, I overwrote `Inline.order` to be the same, but included my `'caption'` blotName at the end of the array:

```
// Lower index means deeper in the DOM tree, since not found (-1) is for embeds
Inline.order = [
  'cursor', 'inline',   // Must be lower
  'code', 'underline', 'strike', 'italic', 'bold', 'script',
  'link', 'caption'     // Must be higher
];
```

And it worked!